# Robot framework: locator for button with no id or name

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to make Robot framework click on a button which is inside an iframe. After selecting the iframe with `select frame` the button's locator cannot be found. Is there any way to find the locator properly?

Button HTML:

```html
<button _ngcontent-wwc-c83="" soho-menu-button="" icon="add" menu="add-popupmenu" class="btn-primary btn-icon right-content__add-btn btn-menu has-tooltip hide-focus" _nghost-wwc-c43="" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="add-popupmenu">
   <svg _ngcontent-wwc-c43="" soho-icon="" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon">
      <use href="#icon-add"></use>
   </svg>
   <!----><!---->
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `svg` tag, you may wanna use the below xpath :

```
//*[name()='svg' and @class='icon']
```

Check in HTMLDOM that we have a unique entry or not before proceeding further.